# Returning count using multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Forgive my ignorance, but sql-server is not my strong suit. I'm trying to retrieve the count of rows from two mapping tables using subqueries (correlated subqueries?). If I remove one subquery, things work fine, but if I include both subqueries, I'm not getting the expected number of rows back.

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    al_1.locationid as LocationCount,
    af_1.FuncAreaId as FuncAreaCount

FROM
    application as a inner join
    applicationlocation as al_1 on a.id = al_1.appid inner join
    applicationfuncarea as af_1 on a.id = af_1.AppId
WHERE
    al_1.locationid in
        (
            SELECT count(locationid)
            FROM applicationlocation as al_2
            WHERE al_2.appid = al_1.appid
        )
AND 
    af_1.funcareaid in 
        (
            SELECT count(funcareaid)
            FROM applicationfuncarea as af_2
            WHERE af_2.appid = af_1.appid
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken about what you want to achieve here, then this can be achieved by using grouping with `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` operators:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT al_1.locationid) as LocationCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT af_1.FuncAreaId) as FuncAreaCount
FROM
    application as a inner join
    applicationlocation as al_1 on a.id = al_1.appid inner join
    applicationfuncarea as af_1 on a.id = af_1.AppId
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

It is hard to tell if result is correct without seeing your data and expected result. If the above does not work, try removing `DISTINCT` operators and see if you get the results that you need.

Comment: This looks very similar to the solution that our senior dev helped me produce, except that **a.name** was not included in the `GROUP BY` clause and the aggregate function `MAX` was used regarding **a.name** in the `SELECT` clause. Thank you for your help, I'm going to mark this as the solution.